# Mobile Android Chrome choppy laggy scroll after "window.scrollTo" with "behavior: smooth"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, scroll, mobile-chrome

In my React app a have a product list with a `pageNav` component.

I show 8 products per page, so when you click on the `NextPage` button (which is located at the bottom of the list), I need to scroll the user back to the top, so you see the top of the next page.

This is because my `ResultList` component will basically re-render synchronously (no API calls) to render the products for the next page. If I don't scroll you back to the top, you'll see the bottom of the next page, and it makes no sense.

The way I was doing it, when you click on the `NextPage` button:

```
window.scrollTo({
  top: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

I did it like this 'cause I think the smooth effect keeps the user 100% aware of what is happening to the page.

After the first load, Chrome behaves normally, you can scroll up and down just fine. But after you click on `PrevPage` or `NextPage` buttons to change to see other products, you'll see the auto smooth scroll happening to get back to the top of the page, but from that point on you'll get extremely choppy and laggy scroll for the page. It get stucks everywhere down and up.

Firefox seems to handle the smooth scroll just fine. Even after changing pages several times, the user scroll works fine.

This is only happening on Mobile Chrome. Firefox is working fine. Safari wasn't tested.

```
Samsung Galaxy A5 2017
Android 8.0.0
Chrome Mobile 79.0.3945.136
```

**What I had to do:**

I removed the scroll effect.

```
window.scrollTo({
  top: 0
});
```

And now it's working fine again, but I lost the smooth effect on page transitions.

**QUESTION**

Has anyone experienced this issue?

Is there a workaround to this, so I can keep the smooth effect?

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly the same issue but i dont have any idea of how to fix it neither. Lets see if someone can put some light to this problem. Opera Mobile seems to handle smooth scrolling fine as well.

**Edit. Solved:**

I solved it. Instead of using window.scrollTo you can use this:

```
element.scrollIntoView({ 
   behavior: 'smooth' 
});
```

Select the first element of your next page list and use **element.scrollIntoView**

**PD:** Seems like the window.scrollTo is a bug from Chrome Mobile. You can use what i told you above in the meantime they dont fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that to see if it works for me too!

Comment: Great, it works! Btw Firefox mobile on Android does not have this bug. Did someone reported this bug to chromium team?

Answer (score 1):

Laggy scrollTo may be caused by default scroll event. ScrollTo does it's job and scrolls, but default event may be also scrolling. If you have scrollTo triggered by any listener, add "passive: false" to it, and prevent default in your function. My example:

```
window.addEventListener("wheel", (e) => scrollToSection(e), {
  passive: false,
});

const scrollToSection = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();

 window.scrollTo({
   top: value,
   left: value,
   behavior: "smooth",
 });
};
```